# C++ gdb error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, biginteger

I am trying to solve a problem that it want the program to output the result of n^84601. (n=0,1,...,10)
Therefore, I try to solve it by using big integer, and it works well in small number, but segfault in bigger ones.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MX = 100000;
struct BigInt {
    int ar[MX];
    int len;
    BigInt(int n) {
        int i = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            ar[i] = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            i++;
        }
        len = i;
    }
    BigInt times(BigInt x) {
        BigInt tmp(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x.len; j++) {
                int r = ar[i] * x.ar[j] + tmp.ar[i + j];
                tmp.ar[i + j] = r % 10;
                tmp.ar[i + j + 1] += r / 10;
            }
        }
        for (int i = min(len + x.len, MX - 1);; i--) {
            if (tmp.ar[i] != 0) {
                tmp.len = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    void print() {
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            cout << ar[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};
BigInt poww(BigInt a, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return a;
    }
    BigInt x = poww(a, n / 2);
    BigInt y = x.times(x);
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
        y = y.times(a);
    }
    return y;
}
int main(void) {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n;
    while (cin >> n) {
        if (n == 0)
            cout << 0 << endl;
        else if (n == 1)
            cout << 1 << endl;
        else
            poww(BigInt(n), 86401).print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the `MX` in to `10000` and `86401` into `864`, it can correctly caculate 2^864. But it will segfault with 2^86401.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more clever to support an "arbitrary" number of digits in a `BigInt`. I would use a `std::vector` for `ar`. `segfault` for bigger numbers sounds to me whether something went out of range... With a debugger, the "post-crash" analysis of callstack should tell you where.

Answer (score 3):

You have a stack overflow.

- Your `BigInt` object is quite large: it contains 100001 `int`s, which is usually 400,004 bytes.
- You allocate several of these on the stack (some are unnecessary: you should really pass arguments by const reference).
- You have recursion.
- A typical stack size limit is 8MB.

Combine above statements together, and you can see that you can have at most 20 `BigInt`s on the stack at one time. Your recursion depth is at least 17, so creating more than one `BigInt` on the stack for each recursive call is guaranteed to fail.

There are a few solutions:

- use more efficient encoding -- currently you are using `int` to hold one digit, `unsigned char` would be more appropriate
- allocate space for digits on heap instead of on the stack. If you do that, be aware of the [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).